# Prove that equal lattices have fundamental periods related by invertible integer matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel like I must be missing something obvious. The goal is to prove that $\omega_1 \mathbb Z \oplus \omega_2\mathbb Z = \alpha_1 \mathbb Z \oplus \alpha_2 \mathbb Z$ (where $\omega_1, \omega_2, \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb C$, $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$, and $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$) if and only if there is some matrix $M \in GL_2(\mathbb Z)$ such that
$$\left[\begin{matrix}\omega_1 \\ \omega_2\end{matrix}\right] = M \left[\begin{matrix}\alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2\end{matrix}\right].$$
Showing that if $M$ exists then the lattices are equal is very simple, but I am having a surprisingly difficult time proving the forward direction. I note that if the two lattices are equal, then there exist matrices $A, B \in M_2(\mathbb Z)$ such that
$$\omega = A \alpha \text{ and } \alpha = B \omega$$
(where $\omega = [\omega_1 \ \omega_2]^T$ and $\alpha = [\alpha_1 \ \alpha_2]^T$), so then
$$AB\omega = A\alpha = \omega \\ BA\alpha = B\omega = \alpha,$$
so both $AB$ and $BA$ have an eigenvalue of 1. Furthermore, $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial $(\lambda - 1)(\lambda - e)$, and we must have $e \in \mathbb Z$ since $A, B \in M_2(\mathbb Z)$. What I'm trying to do is show that $e^2 = 1$ so that $\det(AB) = \det(BA) = \pm 1$, and then it would follow that $\det(A), \det(B) = \pm 1$, so then $\omega = A\alpha$ with $A \in GL_2(\mathbb Z)$. Is this a reasonable way to prove the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **Theorem 1** in [this link](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi10/cse206a/lec1.pdf). Basically, the fact that $A,B \in M_2(\mathbb Z)$ implies that $\det(A), \det(B)\in\mathbb{Z}$, so they end up being $\pm1$ necessarily.

Comment: I guess the main point is to view my $\omega$ as an invertible 2x2 real matrix, and then use that $(AB - I)\omega = 0$ to say that $AB = I$, so $A$ and $B$ are invertible. Good reference!